# SQL Server backup to file with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Is it possible to create backup file from a SQL Server database programmatically with C# (without using SMO or changing permissions)? SQL Server hasn't rights to create (write) `*.bak` file in user folder, but program can do this. So I want to create some query to database that will give dump of database, that I can write in file.

Something like that:

```
SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(@"backup database test1 to stream", cnnct);
SqlDataReader r = sc.ExecuteReader();
while(r.read())file.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
```

Comment: http://sqldumper.ruizata.com/

Comment: The correct way *is* with SMO, and requires the appropriate permissions (which you may not have). Why are you refusing to do this?

Comment: Because SMO requires (as I understood) specific version's of SQL server(there are dll's for 2005,08,12 and etc).

Comment: SMO works across versions, at least looking backwards AFAIK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is neither possible nor a good idea. MSSQL databases are too complex to be reliably dumped as SQL. I know of no tool that gets this right all the time.

**The right way** to deal with this is to give the SQL Server user the rights to access that folder. Find out what user is being used (maybe procexp.exe?) and add the necessary rights.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but the main idea that dump should be made by making queries to DB( using code and etc) without changing basic rights.

Comment: Ok. So I recommend you use SMO to script schema and data. It can do both. SMO is independent of SQL Server version. Just use the newest SMO available.

Comment: Independed? So I can use smo library from 2008 server for 2005 and 2012 server?

Comment: Well, the SMO lib has to be >= the server version (I think...). But it is backwards compatible for sure. Just use 2012 SMO and you can access everything.

Answer (score 0):

YEs it is, but is **way** more complicated than you think. You need to implement a [VDI specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17282) component (which is by definition native code, not managed). Then you can load this VDI into SQL Server and backup into it. See [SHEDDING LIGHT on VSS & VDI Backups in SQL Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2009/04/28/informational-shedding-light-on-vss-vdi-backups-in-sql-server.aspx). Have alook at [SQL Server Compressed Backup](http://mssqlcompressed.sourceforge.net/).

Of course is very unlikely this is what you want, folk who implement VDI do not need to ask such questions. So what is what you *really* try to do? It seems that what you want is more to *Script out* the database, for which there is [SMO Scripter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scripter.aspx).